Is the set containing all the limit points of its complement always closed?
I know that a set $A$ is closed if and only if $d(A)\subseteq A$, where $d(~)$ denotes the derived set.
However, can a set be always closed if $d(A^c)\subseteq A$.

$\partial A = \partial A^c$

@Jakobian, sorry I meant $d(A)$ not $b(A)$.

You should clarify your notations. What is $d(A)$ ?

@NaNoS, $d(A)$ is the set of all limit points of $A$. $b(A)$ is the set of all boundary points of $A$.

If $d(A^c)\subseteq A$ then each $x\in A^c$ is isolated in $A^c$, so $A^c$ is discrete. Conversely, if $A^c$ is discrete then $d(A^c)\subseteq A$. All sets $A$ such that $d(A^c)\subseteq A$ are closed iff all sets $A$ such that $A^c$ is discrete are closed. That is, all discrete sets are open. That is, all singletons are open. That is, $X$ is discrete. So if $X$ is not discrete there is always a counter-example.
